# how to implement a listener on an activity to update a listview adaptor

Tags: java, android, android-activity, listener, adaptor

hey everyone hope you can help with this and thanks for looking at my Q.
i need to update the value of

```
public static int hScoreGen1 = 0; (activity A)
```

from another activity (activity B).
The value of `hScoreGen1` is displayed in a listview in activity A

```
//Activity A

public void setList1(){

        HashMap<String,String> temp = new HashMap<String,String>();
        temp.put("catGeneral","Level 1");
        temp.put("score1", String.valueOf(hScoreGen1) + "/10");
        listGeneral.add(temp);
        }
```

and

```
//Activity A    

adapter1 = new SimpleAdapter(
                    this,

                listGeneral,
                R.layout.list_highscore_row,
                new String[] {"catGeneral","score1"},
                new int[] {R.id.text1,R.id.text2}
        );
```

and

```
//Activity A
public static  SimpleAdapter adapter1;
```

and this changes the value

```
Activity B

if (totalCorrect > ScoreScreen.currentScoreCatValue){

                                HighScores.hScoreGen1 = totalCorrect;
                                HighScores.adapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
```

i was told making the adapter static could cause leaks. instead for listener just create an interface, implement this over the Activity where i want to update the score. Set this listener object in the base activity [apply the null check] and set the listener from second activity. which sounds right but carnt find code example of this....if your have any ideas they would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution would be to use a [Singleton](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/singleton-design-pattern-an-introspection-and-best-practices.html) class in which you store your int *hScoreGen1* :

```
public class Singleton {

    private static Singleton instance;
    public static int hScoreGen1 = 0;

    private Singleton() {
    }

    public static Singleton getInstance() {

        if (instance == null)
            instance = new Singleton();
        return instance;
    }

    public void setScore(int score) {

        this.hScoreGen1 = score;
    }

    public int getScore(int score) {

        return this.hScoreGen1;
    }    
}
```

This way, your variable *hScoreGen* will be initialized only once, and you'll be able to set its value in `Activity` A and display it in `Activity` B :

```
public class ActivityA extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(...) {
        Singleton score = Singleton.getInstance();
        score.setScore(10);

        ...
    }
}



public class ActivityB extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(...) {
        Singleton score = Singleton.getInstance();
        TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view);
        textView.setText(score.getScore());

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: interesting, but surely their must be a simpler way as im only changing a value of a var. would broadcast receiver be simpler

Comment: OK I understand. [This link](http://developer.android.com/guide/faq/framework.html#3) might help if you haven't seen it yet. I personally always used the kind of methods described there instead of using broadcasts :).